# Document Class for Recipes

Tags: packages, templates, document-classes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A cookbook in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20549/a-cookbook-in-latex)

I'm trying to find a package I can use to typeset cooking recipes. I would especially like to find something that keeps the ingredients to the left and the instructions for using them just to the right of the ingredients as they are being used. This is an approach used in many cooking books for professionals chefs.

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: There are some nice classes that will do this See:  [A cookbook in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20549/2693).

Answer (score 5):

there are several possibilities to be found using a [ctan search](http://www.ctan.org/search?search=recipe&search_type=description).

the one that looks most promising, keeping ingredients to the left and instructions to the right, is [cuisine](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cuisine).  this appears to be on tex live as well, so the instructions can be viewed via `texdoc cuisine`.