# Comprehensive overview of the existing latex classes. Or how to choose the right class?

Tags: packages, document-classes, book-design

Latex classes are really useful as they provide ready and easy to use implementation of complex formatting, styling and rendering methods. In fact, it is one of the most interesting feature of the latex system.

Choosing a class (and packages) is thus a critical issue prior to write any latex document. Choosing THE class suited for your project's needs may save you a lot of time wasted to implement basic features and manage packages incompatibilities and limitations.

Actually, I am using only a limited and general set of classes: article, beamer, report and book. But these classes do not allow me to do all I'd like to, at least in a rapid and easy way.

Searching for specific solutions to my problems one by one as the arise in the writing process has not been a satisfactory strategy and generated a lot of frustration. As my problems maybe be complex, multiple, interrelated and evolve during my writing projects, specific solutions found are often incompatible with my previous work or need a complete redesign of my implementation or are ugly-and-drawback-prone patches.

My question is: **Is there a comprehensive overview of the different latex classes?**

By comprehensive I mean: not necessarily the most complete and detailed ressource, but concise informations focused on existing classes' capabilities, forces/weakness, limitations, use of packages and incompatibilities with other packages.

Comment: Doing `ack '\.cls$' $(kpsewhich -a ls-R) | wc -l` gives 577. A comprehensive comparison would take quite a long time.

Comment: @egreg `ack`...?

Comment: @cfr A “better grep”. Doing `grep -c '\.cls$' /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/ls-R` produces `574` (I have three classes in TEXMFLOCAL).

Comment: Interesting ideas. But I agree that it would need some time to work on it. Are you aware of existing ressource on that topic: blogs, web pages, books, pdfs, etc...? thx.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/782/what-are-the-available-documentclass-types-and-their-uses Seen this one?

Comment: I think it would be more useful if you are asking *level-one classification* such as classifying by object or classifying by bundle.

Comment: @cfr -- Due to a naming conflict in various GNU/Linux distros, [`ack`](http://beyondgrep.com/) is sometimes found in the respositories (e.g., Debian) as `ack-grep` (which you then want to symlink back to `ack` to make the command 'convenient' to type).

Comment: Its true that my actual formulation look as a duplicate of this former question. But It do not address all the issues I'm interested in. I'll reformulate my question (but not now).

Answer (score 19):

The texlive package database has a one line description of each (texlive) package, derived I think from the ctan catalogue.

$ pwd
/usr/local/texlive/2014/tlpkg

```
 for i in `grep  -l  '\.cls' tlpobj/* ` ;do echo "";grep "^\(name\|shortdesc\| *texmf-dist.*\.cls\)" $i| sed -e "s@texmf.*/@@" ; done > cls.txt
```

produces a file with 588 */.cls references that looks like

`a0poster`

> Support for designing posters on large paper.
>   a0poster.cls

`aastex`

> Macros for Manuscript Preparation for AAS Journals.
>   aastex.cls

`abntex2`

> Typeset technical and scientific Brazilian documents based on ABNT rules.
>   abntex2.cls

`achemso`

> Support for American Chemical Society journal submissions.
>   achemso.cls

`acmconf`

> Class for ACM conference proceedings.
>   acmconf.cls

`active-conf`

> Class for typesetting ACTIVE conference papers.
>   active-conf.cls

`adfathesis`

> Australian Defence Force Academy thesis format.
>   adfathesis.cls

`afparticle`

> Typesetting articles for Archives of Forensic Psychology
>   afparticle.cls

`afthesis`

> Air Force Institute of Technology thesis class.
>   afthesis.cls

`aguplus`

> Styles for American Geophysical Union.
>   aguplus.cls

`aiaa`

> Typeset AIAA conference papers.
>   aiaa-tc.cls

`akktex`

> A collection of packages and classes.
>   akklecture.cls
>   akkscript.cls
>   akktecdoc.cls

`akletter`

> Comprehensive letter support.
>   akletter.cls
>   myletter.cls

`ametsoc`

> Official American Meteorological Society Latex Template.
>   ametsoc.cls

`amscls`

> AMS document classes for LaTeX.
>   amsart.cls
>   amsbook.cls
>   amsdtx.cls
>   amsldoc.cls
>   amsproc.cls

`aomart`

> Typeset articles for the Annals of Mathematics.
>   aomart.cls

`apa`

> American Psychological Association format.
>   apa.cls

`apa6`

> Format documents in APA style (6th edition).
>   apa6.cls

`apa6e`

> Format manuscripts to APA 6th edition guidelines.
>   apa6e.cls

`arabtex`

> Macros and fonts for typesetting Arabic.
>   arabart.cls
>   arabbook.cls
>   arabrep.cls
>   arabrep1.cls

`articleingud`

> LaTeX class for articles published in INGENIERIA review.
>   articleingud.cls

`asaetr`

> Transactions of the ASAE.
>   asaetr.cls

`ascelike`

> Bibliography style for the ASCE.
>   ascelike.cls

`assignment`

> A class file for typesetting homework and lab assignments
>   assignment.cls

`bangorcsthesis`

> Typeset a thesis at Bangor University.
>   bangorcsthesis.cls

`bangtex`

> Writing Bangla and Assamese with LaTeX.
>   barticle.cls
>   bbook.cls
>   bletter.cls

`bankstatement`

> A LaTeX class for bank statements based on csv data.
>   bankstatement.cls

`basque-book`

> Class for book-type documents written in Basque.
>   basque-book.cls

`beamer`

> A LaTeX class for producing presentations and slides.
>   beamer.cls

`beamer-FUBerlin`

> Beamer, using the style of FU Berlin.
>   FUbeamer.cls

`bgteubner`

> Class for producing books for the publisher "Teubner Verlag".
>   bgteubner.cls

`bhcexam`

> An exam class designed for Mathematics Teachers in China.
>   BHCexam.cls

`biblatex-musuos`

> A biblatex style for citations in musuos.cls.

`bidi`

> Bidirectional typesetting in plain TeX and LaTeX, using XeTeX engine.
>   bidimoderncv.cls
>   biditufte-book.cls
>   biditufte-handout.cls

`bidipresentation`

> Experimental bidi presentation.
>   bidipresentation.cls

`bookcover`

> A class for book covers and dust jackets.
>   bookcover.cls

`bookest`

> Extended book class.
>   bookest.cls

`brandeis-dissertation`

> Class for Brandeis University dissertations.
>   brandeis-dissertation.cls

`bxjscls`

> Document classes based on jsclasses.
>   bxjsarticle.cls
>   bxjsreport.cls

`cascadilla`

> Typeset papers conforming to the stylesheet of the Cascadilla Proceedings Project.
>   cascadilla.cls

`cd`

> Typeset CD covers.
>   cd.cls

`cd-cover`

> Typeset CD covers.
>   cd-cover.cls

`cdpbundl`

> Business letters in the Italian style.
>   articoletteracdp.cls
>   letteracdp.cls

`chbibref`

> Change the Bibliography/References title.

`chletter`

> Class for typesetting letters to Swiss rules.
>   chletter.cls

`cnbwp`

> Typeset working papers of the Czech National Bank.
>   cnbwp.cls

`cnltx`

> LaTeX tools and documenting facilities.
>   cnltx-doc.cls

`codedoc`

> LaTeX code and documentation in LaTeX-format file.
>   codedoc.cls

`combine`

> Bundle individual documents into a single document.
>   combine.cls

`computational-complexity`

> Class for the journal Computational Complexity.
>   cc.cls

`concepts`

> Keeping track of formal 'concepts' for a particular field.
>   packagedoc.cls

`concprog`

> Concert programmes.
>   ConcProg.cls

`confproc`

> A set of tools for generating conference proceedings.
>   confproc.cls

`contracard`

> Generate calling cards for dances.
>   contracard.cls

`courseoutline`

> Prepare university course outlines.
>   courseoutline.cls

`coursepaper`

> Prepare university course papers.
>   coursepaper.cls

`csbulletin`

> LaTeX class for articles submitted to the CSTUG Bulletin (Zpravodaj).
>   csbulletin.cls

`ctex`

> LaTeX classes and packages for Chinese typesetting.
>   ctexartutf8.cls
>   ctexbookutf8.cls
>   ctexreputf8.cls
>   ctexart.cls
>   ctexbook.cls
>   ctexrep.cls

`curve`

> A class for making curriculum vitae.
>   curve.cls

`cv4tw`

> LaTeX CV class, with extended details.
>   cv4tw.cls

`cweb-latex`

> A LaTeX version of CWEB.
>   cweb-hy.cls
>   cweb.cls

`dccpaper`

> Typeset papers for the International Journal of Digital Curation
>   idcc.cls
>   ijdc-v9.cls

`dcpic`

> Commutative diagrams in a LaTeX and TeX documents.
>   europroc.cls

`dickimaw`

> Books and tutorials from the "Dickimaw LaTeX Series".
>   novices.cls
>   dickimawthesis.cls

`dinbrief`

> German letter DIN style.
>   dinbrief.cls

`disser`

> Class and templates for typesetting dissertations in Russian.
>   disser.cls
>   gost732.cls

`dithesis`

> dithesis.cls

`droit-fr`

> Document class and bibliographic style for French law.
>   droit-fr.cls

`dtk`

> Document class for the journal of DANTE.
>   dtk.cls

`dvdcoll`

> A class for typesetting DVD archives
>   dvdcoll.cls

`ebsthesis`

> Typesetting theses for economics
>   ebsthesis.cls

`economic`

> BibTeX support for submitting to Economics journals.
>   agecon.cls
>   ajae.cls
>   apecon.cls
>   ecca.cls
>   erae.cls
>   itaxpf.cls
>   jrurstud.cls
>   njf.cls
>   oegatb.cls
>   pocoec.cls
>   regstud.cls
>   worlddev.cls

`ecv`

> A fancy Curriculum Vitae class.
>   ecv.cls

`einfuehrung`

> Examples from the book Einfuhrung in LaTeX.
>   beispiel.cls
>   bspcalweekly.cls
>   bspdvdcoll.cls
>   bspfont.cls
>   bsppstricks.cls
>   exaarticle.cls
>   exaarticle2.cls
>   exaartplain.cls
>   exabeamer.cls
>   exabook.cls
>   exabook2.cls
>   exadante.cls
>   exafoils.cls
>   exafubeamer.cls
>   exafupd.cls
>   examargin.cls
>   examemoir.cls
>   examinimal-mathsymbols.cls
>   examinimal.cls
>   exapd.cls
>   exaprosper.cls
>   exareport.cls
>   exaseminar.cls
>   exaslidenotes.cls
>   exasymbol.cls
>   exaxetex.cls
>   screxa.cls
>   screxabook.cls
>   screxareport.cls

`ejpecp`

> Class for EJP and ECP.
>   ejpecp.cls

`elbioimp`

> A LaTeX document class for the Journal of Electrical Bioimpedance.
>   elbioimp.cls

`elpres`

> A simple class for electronic presentations
>   elpres.cls

`elsarticle`

> Class for articles for submission to Elsevier journals.
>   elsarticle.cls

`elteikthesis`

> Thesis class for ELTE University Informatics wing.
>   elteikthesis.cls

`elzcards`

> Typeset business cards, index cards and flash cards easyly.
>   elzcards.cls

`emulateapj`

> Produce output similar to that of APJ.
>   emulateapj.cls

`erdc`

> Style for Reports by US Army Corps of Engineers.
>   erdc.cls

`eskd`

> Modern Russian typesetting.
>   eskd.cls

`eskdx`

> Modern Russian typesetting.
>   eskdgraph.cls.in
>   eskdtab.cls.in
>   eskdtext.cls.in
>   eskdgraph.cls
>   eskdtab.cls
>   eskdtext.cls

`estcpmm`

> Style for Munitions Management Project Reports.
>   estcpmm.cls

`europasscv`

> Unofficial class for the new version of the Europass curriculum vitae
>   europasscv.cls

`europecv`

> Unofficial class for European curricula vitae.
>   europecv.cls

`exam`

> Package for typesetting exam scripts.
>   exam.cls

`examdesign`

> LaTeX class for typesetting exams.
>   examdesign.cls

`exam-n`

> Exam class, focused on collaborative authoring.
>   exam-n.cls
>   exam-n.cls

`excludeonly`

> Prevent files being \include-ed.

`extsizes`

> Extend the standard classes' size options.
>   extarticle.cls
>   extbook.cls
>   extletter.cls
>   extproc.cls
>   extreport.cls

`facsimile`

> Document class for preparing faxes.
>   facsimile.cls

`factura`

> Typeset and calculate invoices according to Venezuela law.
>   factura.cls

`facture`

> Generate an invoice.
>   facture.cls

`fancyslides`

> Custom presentation class built upon LaTeX Beamer.
>   fancyslides.cls

`FAQ-en`

> A compilation of Frequently Asked Questions with answers.
>   faq.cls

`fbithesis`

> Computer Science thesis class for University of Dortmund.
>   fbithesis.cls

`flacards`

> Generate flashcards for printing.
>   flacards.cls

`flashcards`

> A class for typesetting flashcards.
>   flashcards.cls

`frletter`

> Typeset letters in the French style.
>   frletter.cls

`gaceta`

> A class to typeset La Gaceta de la RSME.
>   gaceta.cls

`gatech-thesis`

> Georgia Institute of Technology thesis class
>   gatech-thesis.cls

`g-brief`

> Letter document class.
>   g-brief.cls
>   g-brief2.cls

`gmdoc`

> Documentation of LaTeX packages.
>   gmdocc.cls

`gsemthesis`

> Geneva School of Economics and Management PhD thesis format.
>   gsemthesis.cls

`guide-to-latex`

> mpletter.cls

`harnon-cv`

> A CV document class with a vertical timeline for experience.
>   harnon-cv.cls

`hausarbeit-jura`

> Class for writing "juristiche Hausarbeiten" at German Universities.
>   hausarbeit-jura.cls

`hc`

> Replacement for the LaTeX classes.
>   hcart.cls
>   hcletter.cls
>   hcreport.cls
>   hcslides.cls

`hepthesis`

> A class for academic reports, especially PhD theses.
>   hepthesis.cls

`hitec`

> Class for documentation.
>   hitec.cls

`hletter`

> Flexible letter typesetting with flexible page headings.
>   hletter.cls

`hpsdiss`

> A dissertation class.
>   hpsdiss.cls

`hrlatex`

> LaTeX support for Croatian documents.
>   fsbispit.cls

`icsv`

> Class for typesetting articles for the ICSV conference.
>   icsv.cls

`IEEEconf`

> Macros for IEEE conference proceedings.
>   IEEEconf.cls

`IEEEtran`

> Document class for IEEE Transactions journals and conferences.
>   IEEEtran.cls

`ijmart`

> LaTeX Class for the Israel Journal of Mathematics.
>   ijmart.cls

`image-gallery`

> Create an overview of pictures from a digital camera or from other sources.
>   image-gallery.cls

`imsproc`

> Typeset IMS conference proceedings.
>   imsproc.cls

`imtekda`

> IMTEK thesis class.
>   IMTEKda.cls

`iso`

> Generic ISO standards typesetting macros.
>   isov2.cls

`isodoc`

> A LaTeX class for typesetting letters and invoices.
>   isodoc.cls

`iwhdp`

> Halle Institute for Economic Research (IWH) Discussion Papers.
>   iwhdp.cls

`jmlr`

> Class files for the Journal of Machine Learning Research.
>   jmlr.cls
>   jmlrbook.cls

`jpsj`

> Document Class for Journal of the Physical Society of Japan.
>   jpsj2.cls

`jsclasses`

> Classes tailored for use with Japanese.
>   jsarticle.cls
>   jsbook.cls
>   jspf.cls
>   kiyou.cls

`jura`

> A document class for German legal texts.
>   jura.cls

`juramisc`

> Typesetting German juridical documents.
>   jurabook.cls
>   juraovw.cls
>   juraurtl.cls

`kdgdocs`

> Document classes for Karel de Grote University College.
>   kdgcoursetext.cls
>   kdgmasterthesis.cls

`kerntest`

> Print tables and generate control files to adjust kernings.
>   kerntest.cls

`kluwer`

> kluwer.cls

`knittingpattern`

> Create knitting patterns.
>   knittingpattern.cls

`komacv`

> Typesetting a beuatiful CV with various style options.
>   komacv.cls

`koma-script`

> A bundle of versatile classes and packages
>   scrguide.cls
>   scrartcl.cls
>   scrbook.cls
>   scrdoc.cls
>   scrlttr2.cls
>   scrreprt.cls

`kotex-oblivoir`

> A LaTeX document class for typesetting Korean documents.
>   oblivoir-base.cls
>   oblivoir-xlua.cls
>   oblivoir.cls
>   xoblivoir.cls

`kpfonts`

> A complete set of fonts for text and mathematics.
>   christophe.cls

`l3kernel`

> LaTeX3 programming conventions.
>   l3doc.cls

`labbook`

> Typeset laboratory journals.
>   labbook.cls

`latex`

> A TeX macro package that defines LaTeX.
>   article.cls
>   book.cls
>   letter.cls
>   ltnews.cls
>   ltxdoc.cls
>   ltxguide.cls
>   minimal.cls
>   proc.cls
>   report.cls
>   slides.cls

`latexfileversion`

> Prints the version and date of a LaTeX class or style file.

`latex-graphics-companion`

> Examples from The LaTeX Graphics Companion.
>   ppex.cls

`latexindent`

> Indent a LaTeX document, highlighting the programming structure.
>   testcls.cls

`latex-referenz`

> Examples from the book "LaTeX Referenz".
>   bspfont.cls
>   exaarticle.cls
>   exaarticle2.cls
>   exabook.cls
>   exabook2.cls
>   examinimal.cls
>   exareport.cls
>   exaxetex.cls
>   screxa.cls
>   screxabook.cls
>   screxareport.cls

`latex-tds`

> A structured copy of the LaTeX distribution.
>   tools-overview.cls

`leaflet`

> Create small handouts (flyers).
>   leaflet.cls

`lettre`

> Letters and faxes in French.
>   lettre.cls

`limap`

> Typeset maps and blocks according to the Information Mapping method.
>   limap.cls

`lps`

> Class for "Logic and Philosophy of Science".
>   lps.cls

`lt3graph`

> Provide a graph datastructure for experimental LaTeX3.
>   lt3graph-packagedoc.cls

`ltxdockit`

> Documentation support.
>   ltxdockit.cls

`ltxmisc`

> Miscellaneous LaTeX packages, etc.
>   abstbook.cls
>   beletter.cls
>   flashcard.cls
>   iagproc.cls

`luaintro`

> Examples from the book "Einfuhrung in LuaTeX und LuaLaTeX".
>   beispiel.cls
>   bspcalweekly.cls
>   bspdvdcoll.cls
>   bspfont.cls
>   bsppstricks.cls
>   exaarticle.cls
>   exaarticle2.cls
>   exaartplain.cls
>   exabeamer.cls
>   exabook.cls
>   exabook2.cls
>   exadante.cls
>   exafoils.cls
>   exafubeamer.cls
>   exafupd.cls
>   examargin.cls
>   examemoir.cls
>   examinimal-mathsymbols.cls
>   examinimal.cls
>   exapd.cls
>   exaprosper.cls
>   exareport.cls
>   exaseminar.cls
>   exaslidenotes.cls
>   exasymbol.cls
>   exaxetex.cls
>   screxa.cls
>   screxabook.cls
>   screxareport.cls

`lualatex-doc`

> A guide to use of LaTeX with LuaTeX.
>   lltxdoc.cls

`luatexja`

> Typeset Japanese with lua(la)tex.
>   ltjarticle.cls
>   ltjbook.cls
>   ltjltxdoc.cls
>   ltjreport.cls
>   ltjsarticle.cls
>   ltjsbook.cls
>   ltjskiyou.cls
>   ltjspf.cls

`mafr`

> Mathematics in accord with French usage.
>   cours.cls
>   fiche.cls

`matc3mem`

> Class for MatematicaC3 textbooks.
>   matc3mem.cls

`math-e`

> Examples from the book Typesetting Mathematics with LaTeX.
>   exaarticle.cls
>   exaarticle2.cls
>   exaartplain.cls
>   exareport.cls
>   exasymbol.cls

`mcmthesis`

> Template designed for MCM/ICM
>   mcmthesis.cls

`mdframed`

> Framed environments that can split at page boundaries.
>   ltxmdf.cls

`meetingmins`

> Format written minutes of meetings.
>   meetingmins.cls

`memoir`

> Typeset fiction, non-fiction and mathematical books.
>   memoir.cls

`mentis`

> A basis for books to be published by Mentis publishers.
>   mentis.cls

`mil3`

> Samples from Math into LaTeX, third edition.
>   svsing6.cls

`moderncv`

> A modern curriculum vitae class.
>   moderncv.cls

`msu-thesis`

> Class for Michigan State University Master's and PhD theses.
>   msu-thesis.cls

`mugsthesis`

> Thesis class complying with Marquette University Graduate School requirements.
>   mugsthesis.cls

`musuos`

> Typeset papers for the department of music, Osnabruck.
>   musuos.cls

`muthesis`

> Classes for University of Manchester Dept of Computer Science.
>   muthesis.cls
>   third-rep.cls

`mwcls`

> Polish-oriented document classes.
>   mwart.cls
>   mwbk.cls
>   mwrep.cls

`mycv`

> A list-driven CV class, allowing TikZ decorations.
>   mycv.cls

`nature`

> Prepare papers for the journal Nature.
>   nature.cls

`ncclatex`

> An extended general-purpose class
>   ncc.cls
>   nccproc.cls
>   sibjnm.cls

`nddiss`

> Notre Dame Dissertation format class.
>   nddiss2e.cls

`ndsu-thesis`

> North Dakota State University disquisition class.
>   ndsu-thesis.cls

`newlfm`

> Write letters, facsimiles, and memos.
>   newlfm.cls

`nih`

> A class for NIH grant applications.
>   nih.cls

`nlctdoc`

> Package documentation class.
>   nlctdoc.cls

`noindentafter`

> Tool to prevent paragraph indentation after environments/macros.
>   noindentafter-packagedoc.cls

`nostarch`

> LaTeX class for No Starch Press.
>   nostarch.cls

`nrc`

> Class for the NRC technical journals.
>   nrc1.cls
>   nrc2.cls

`ntgclass`

> "European" versions of standard classes.
>   artikel1.cls
>   artikel2.cls
>   artikel3.cls
>   boek.cls
>   boek3.cls
>   brief.cls
>   rapport1.cls
>   rapport3.cls

`octavo`

> Typeset books following classical design and layout.
>   octavo.cls

`onrannual`

> Class for Office of Naval Research Ocean Battlespace Sensing annual report.
>   onrannual.cls

`paper`

> Versions of article class, tuned for scholarly publications.
>   journal.cls
>   paper.cls

`papertex`

> Class for newspapers, etc.
>   papertex.cls

`pbsheet`

> Problem sheet class.
>   pbsheet.cls
>   pbsheet.cls

`pecha`

> Print Tibetan text in the classic pecha layout style.
>   pecha.cls

`petiteannonce`

> A class for small advertisements.
>   petiteannonce.cls

`philosophersimprint`

> Typesetting articles for "Philosophers' Imprint".
>   philosophersimprint.cls

`pinlabel`

> A TeX labelling package.
>   gtpart.cls

`pittetd`

> Electronic Theses and Dissertations at Pitt.
>   pittetd.cls

`pkgloader`

> Managing the options and loading order of other packages.
>   pkgloader-packagedoc.cls

`pkuthss`

> LaTeX template for dissertations in Peking University.
>   pkuthss.cls

`plari`

> Typesetting stageplay scripts.
>   plari.cls

`play`

> Typeset drama using LaTeX.
>   play.cls

`postcards`

> Facilitates mass-mailing of postcards (junkmail).
>   postcards.cls

`powerdot`

> A presentation class.
>   powerdot.cls

`powerdot-FUBerlin`

> Powerdot, using the style of FU Berlin.
>   FUpowerdot.cls

`ppr-prv`

> Prosper preview.
>   ppr-prv.cls

`pracjourn`

> Typeset articles for PracTeX.
>   pracjourn.cls

`presentations-en`

> Examples from the book Presentations with LaTeX.
>   beispiel.cls
>   bspcalweekly.cls
>   bspdvdcoll.cls
>   bspfont.cls
>   bsppstricks.cls
>   exaarticle.cls
>   exaarticle2.cls
>   exaartplain.cls
>   exabeamer.cls
>   exabook.cls
>   exabook2.cls
>   exadante.cls
>   exafoils.cls
>   exafubeamer.cls
>   exafupd.cls
>   examargin.cls
>   examemoir.cls
>   examinimal-mathsymbols.cls
>   examinimal.cls
>   exapd.cls
>   exaprosper.cls
>   exareport.cls
>   exaseminar.cls
>   exaslidenotes.cls
>   exasymbol.cls
>   exaxetex.cls
>   prosper.cls
>   screxa.cls
>   screxabook.cls
>   screxareport.cls
>   slidenotes.cls

`pressrelease`

> A class for typesetting press releases.
>   pressrelease.cls

`proposal`

> A class for preparing proposals.
>   proposal.cls
>   reporting.cls
>   dfgproposal.cls
>   dfgreporting.cls
>   euproposal.cls
>   eureporting.cls

`prosper`

> LaTeX class for high quality slides.
>   prosper.cls

`protocol`

> A class for minutes of meetings.
>   protocol.cls

`przechlewski-book`

> Examples from Przechlewski's LaTeX book.
>   upmgr.cls
>   wkmgr.cls

`pstricks`

> PostScript macros for TeX.
>   pst-doc.cls

`pstricks-examples`

> PSTricks examples.
>   beispiel.cls
>   bspcalweekly.cls
>   bspdvdcoll.cls
>   bspfont.cls
>   bsppstricks.cls
>   exaarticle.cls
>   exaarticle2.cls
>   exaartplain.cls
>   exabeamer.cls
>   exabook.cls
>   exafoils.cls
>   exafubeamer.cls
>   exafupd.cls
>   examargin.cls
>   examinimal.cls
>   exapd.cls
>   exaprosper.cls
>   exareport.cls
>   exaseminar.cls
>   exaslidenotes.cls
>   exasymbol.cls
>   exaxetex.cls
>   screxa.cls
>   screxabook.cls
>   screxareport.cls

`ptex`

> A TeX system for publishing in Japanese.
>   jarticle.cls
>   jbook.cls
>   jltxdoc.cls
>   jreport.cls
>   plnews.cls
>   tarticle.cls
>   tbook.cls
>   treport.cls

`ptptex`

> Macros for 'Progress of Theoretical Physics'.
>   ptptex.cls

`qcm`

> A LaTeX2e class for making multiple choice questionnaires
>   qcm.cls

`recipe`

> A LaTeX class to typeset recipes.
>   recipe.cls

`recipecard`

> Typeset recipes in note-card-sized boxes.
>   recipecard.cls

`refman`

> Format technical reference manuals.
>   refart.cls
>   refrep.cls

`resphilosophica`

> Typeset articles for the journal Res Philosophica.
>   resphilosophica.cls

`resumecls`

> Typeset a resumee in both Chinese and English.
>   resumecls.cls

`revtex`

> Styles for various Physics Journals.
>   revtex4-1.cls

`revtex4`

> revtex4.cls

`rtklage`

> A package for German lawyers
>   rtklage.cls

`ryethesis`

> Class for Ryerson Unversity Graduate School requirements.
>   ryethesis.cls

`sageep`

> Format papers for the annual meeting of EEGS.
>   sageep.cls

`sapthesis`

> Typeset theses for Sapienza-University, Rome.
>   sapthesis.cls

`schule`

> Support for teachers at German schools.
>   schuleab.cls
>   schulein.cls
>   schuleit.cls
>   schulekl.cls
>   schuleub.cls
>   schuleue.cls
>   schullsg.cls
>   schullzk.cls

`schwalbe-chess`

> Typeset the German chess magazine "Die Schwalbe"
>   schwalbe.cls

`sciposter`

> Make posters of ISO A3 size and larger.
>   sciposter.cls

`screenplay`

> A class file to typeset screenplays.
>   screenplay.cls

`scrjrnl`

> Typeset diaries or journals.
>   scrjrnl.cls

`sduthesis`

> Thesis Template of Shandong University
>   sduthesis.cls

`seminar`

> Make overhead slides.
>   seminar.cls

`sesamanuel`

> Class and package for sesamath books or paper
>   sesamanuel.cls

`seuthesis`

> LaTeX template for theses at Southeastern University.
>   zharticle.cls

`sffms`

> Typesetting science fiction/fantasy manuscripts.
>   sffms.cls

`shipunov`

> A collection of LaTeX packages and classes.
>   cassete.cls
>   etiketka.cls

`sidenotes`

> Typeset notes containing rich content, in the margin.
>   caesar_book.cls

`sides`

> A LaTeX class for typesetting stage plays.
>   sides.cls

`simplecv`

> A simple class for writing curricula vitae.
>   simplecv.cls

`simurgh`

> Typeset Parsi in LuaLaTeX.
>   simurgh-doc.cls

`skb`

> Tools for a repository of long-living documents.
>   skbarticle.cls
>   skbbeamer.cls
>   skbbook.cls
>   skblncsbeamer.cls
>   skblncsppt.cls
>   skbmoderncv.cls

`skdoc`

> Documentation and extraction for packages and document classes.
>   skdoc.cls

`skeyval`

> Key-value parsing combining features of xkeyval and pgfkeys.
>   skeyval-testclass.cls

`skrapport`

> 'Simple' class for reports, etc.
>   skrapport.cls

`sphdthesis`

> Latex template for writing PhD Thesis
>   SPhdThesis.cls
>   SPhdThesis.cls

`spie`

> Support for formatting SPIE Proceedings manuscripts.
>   spie.cls

`sr-vorl`

> Class for Springer books.
>   sr-vorl.cls

`sslides`

> Slides with headers and footers.
>   sslides.cls

`stage`

> A LaTeX class for stage plays
>   stage.cls

`standalone`

> Compile TeX pictures stand-alone or as part of a document.
>   standalone.cls

`stellenbosch`

> Stellenbosch thesis bundle.
>   usthesis.cls

`stex`

> An Infrastructure for Semantic Preloading of LaTeX Documents.
>   cnx.cls
>   cnx.cls.ltxml
>   hwexam.cls
>   hwexam.cls.ltxml
>   mikoslides.cls
>   mikoslides.cls.ltxml
>   omdoc.cls
>   omdoc.cls.ltxml

`subfiles`

> Individual typesetting of subfiles of a "main" document.
>   subfiles.cls

`suftesi`

> A document class for typesetting theses, books and articles.
>   suftesi.cls

`sugconf`

> SAS(R) user group conference proceedings document class.
>   sugconf.cls

`tabriz-thesis`

> A template for the University of Tabriz.
>   tabriz-thesis.cls

`talk`

> A LaTeX class for presentations.
>   talk.cls

`tcldoc`

> Doc/docstrip for tcl.
>   tcldoc.cls
>   tclldoc.cls

`tds`

> The TeX Directory Structure standard.
>   tdsguide.cls

`templates-fenn`

> Templates for TeX usage.

`texpower`

> Create dynamic online presentations with LaTeX.
>   powersem.cls

`texworks`

> Cross-platform friendly front end.

`thesis-ekf`

> Thesis class for Eszterhazy Karoly College.
>   thesis-ekf.cls

`thuthesis`

> Thesis template for Tsinghua University.
>   thuthesis.cls

`tikzposter`

> Create scientific posters using TikZ.
>   tikzposter.cls

`tkz-doc`

> Documentation macros for the TKZ series of packages.
>   tkz-doc.cls

`tlc2`

> Examples from "The LaTeX Companion", second edition.
>   ttctexa.cls
>   ttctexamargin.cls
>   ttctexareport.cls

`toptesi`

> Bundle for typesetting multilanguage theses.
>   toptesi.cls

`tudscr`

> Typeset documents in the corporate style of TU Dresden.
>   tudscrartcl.cls
>   tudscrbook.cls
>   tudscrdoc.cls
>   tudscrman.cls
>   tudscrreprt.cls

`tufte-latex`

> Document classes inspired by the work of Edward Tufte.
>   tufte-book.cls
>   tufte-handout.cls
>   tufte-book.cls
>   tufte-handout.cls

`tugboat`

> LaTeX macros for TUGboat articles.
>   ltugboat.cls
>   ltugproc.cls

`tui`

> Thesis style for the University of the Andes, Colombia.
>   tui.cls

`turabian`

> Create Turabian-formatted material using LaTeX.
>   turabian.cls

`turabian-formatting`

> Formatting based on Turabian's Manual.
>   turabian-researchpaper.cls
>   turabian-thesis.cls

`uaclasses`

> University of Arizona thesis and dissertation format.
>   my-thesis.cls
>   ua-thesis.cls

`uadocs`

> Course texts and masters theses in University of Antwerp style.
>   uacoursetext.cls
>   uamasterthesis.cls

`uafthesis`

> Document class for theses at University of Alaska Fairbanks.
>   uafthesis.cls

`ucbthesis`

> ucbthesis.cls

`ucdavisthesis`

> A thesis/dissertation class for University of California at Davis.
>   ucdavisthesis.cls

`ucthesis`

> University of California thesis format.
>   ucthesis.cls

`udesoftec`

> Thesis class for the University of Duisburg-Essen.
>   udesoftec.cls

`uebungsblatt`

> A LaTeX class for writing exercise sheets.
>   uebungsblatt.cls

`uestcthesis`

> Thesis class for UESTC
>   uestcthesis.cls

`uiucredborder`

> Class for UIUC thesis red-bordered forms.
>   uiucredborder.cls

`uiucthesis`

> UIUC thesis class.
>   uiucthesis.cls

`ulthese`

> Thesis class and templates for Universite Laval.
>   ulthese.cls

`umich-thesis`

> University of Michigan Thesis LaTeX class.
>   umich-thesis.cls

`umthesis`

> Dissertations at the University of Michigan.
>   umthesis.cls

`unamth-template`

> UNAM Thesis LaTeX Template
>   PhDthesisPSnPDF.cls
>   PhDthesisPSnPDF.cls.bak

`underoverlap`

> Position decorations over and under expressions.
>   packagedoc.cls

`uothesis`

> Class for dissertations and theses at the University of Oregon.
>   uothesis.cls

`uowthesis`

> Document class for dissertations at the University of Wollongong.
>   UoWthesis.cls

`upmethodology`

> Writing specifications such as for UP-based methodologies.
>   upmethodology-document.cls

`uptex`

> Unicode version of pTeX.
>   ujarticle.cls
>   ujbook.cls
>   ujreport.cls
>   utarticle.cls
>   utbook.cls
>   utreport.cls

`urcls`

> Beamer and scrlttr2 classes and styles for the University of Regensburg.
>   URbeamer.cls
>   URletter.cls

`uspatent`

> U.S. Patent Application Tools for LaTeX and LyX.
>   uspatent.cls

`ut-thesis`

> University of Toronto thesis style.
>   ut-thesis.cls

`uwmslide`

> Slides with a simple Power Point like appearance.
>   uwmslide.cls

`uwthesis`

> University of Washington thesis class.
>   uwthesis.cls

`vntex`

> Support for Vietnamese.
>   vnsample.cls

`withargs`

> Ephemeral macro use.
>   withargs-packagedoc.cls

`wsemclassic`

> LaTeX class for Bavarian school w-seminar papers.
>   wsemclassic.cls

`xepersian`

> Persian for LaTeX, using XeTeX.
>   xepersian-magazine.cls

`xkeyval`

> Extension of the keyval package.
>   xkveca.cls
>   xkvecb.cls

`xypic`

> Flexible diagramming macros.
>   movie.cls

`yathesis`

> yathesis provides a LaTeX class that aims to help to write a thesis following French rules
>   yathesis.cls

`ydoc`

> Macros for documentation of LaTeX classes and packages.
>   ydoc.cls

`york-thesis`

> A thesis class file for York University, Toronto.
>   york-thesis.cls

Comment: thx. Your probably right, the better way is to sit down and to watch the all, one by one. But this kind of list is not really "comprehensive"...

Comment: @jvtrudel Which one is missing?

Comment: This is the [longest post](https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/1655547/longest-post-on-tex-sx) on this site!

Comment: @JasperHabicht and best?