# tlmgr - List only packages, or only classes

Tags: packages, document-classes, tlmgr

The command `tlmgr list --only-installed` gives all packages and classes installed. Is there a way to only have the packages installed? Same question, but only for the classes installed.

This will be used after to call `latexdef -l -p ...` for all packages, and then  `latexdef -l -c ...` for all classes.

Comment: that lists tlmgr pakages not latex ones  so there is no class/package distinction, and latex packages like `longtable` are not listed at all

Comment: What would be the better to inspect all `sty` and `cls` files? Should I have to code my own tool?

Comment: I would use  `find /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex -name \*.sty` or (quicker) `grep '\.sty' $(kpsewhich --all ls-R)`

Comment: Thanks for this.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238236/1090