# TeX Live / CTAN - List of all STY and CLS files

Tags: texlive, ctan, distributions

Is there a database or tool that gives all the `STY` and `CLS` files that are part of TeX Live or CTAN?

I can do some basic web scrapping to retrieve this information, but I would like to avoid having to reprint the roll.

Comment: ctan's catalogue isn't public (too much personal data) but texlive's is see the `/usr/local/texlive/2023/tlpkg/`  data

Comment: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238236/1090

Comment: Note that this is a moving target: the list changes continually.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- nice list of class files, but I didn't see any `.sty` information that I know is in some of the packages shown.

Comment: @barbarabeeton because I filtered on `.cls` there as that was asked at the time, you could do the same for .`sty` (but the list would probably be too long for this site)

Comment: I suspect you could also use `tlmgr`, though I've not actually tried it.

Comment: @cfr `tlmgr list --all` gives packages and classes, whereas the David Carliste's solution gives more information.

Comment: @projetmbc Yes, but `tlmgr` has a lot of options and can use remote databases, too, but, as I said, I didn't test the idea.

Comment: @cfr `tlmgr info | grep english` seems to be what I am looking for.

Comment: Some packages, such as `libertinus-fonts`, have neither `sty` nor `cls`, just fonts. The related `libertinus-otf` package (separate installation) has `sty`.

Comment: My concern is more about avoiding conflict names and unused packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, it looks like you found a solution.

But, as I was interested, I've created [ctan-scraper.py](https://github.com/cmhughes/ctan-scraper/)

If you run, for example,

```
ctan-scraper.py --path "macros/latex/contrib/abnt/" --output myfile1.txt ".*?\.cls"
```

then you receive

```
INFO - [re.compile('macros'), re.compile('latex'), re.compile('contrib'), re.compile('abnt')]
INFO - mirror: https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/
INFO - https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/abntex2/tex/abntex2.cls
INFO - https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/abntexto/abntexto.cls
INFO - https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex2e/contrib/abntex2/tex/abntex2.cls
INFO - https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex2e/contrib/abntexto/abntexto.cls
INFO - https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/abntex2/tex/abntex2.cls
INFO - https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/abntexto/abntexto.cls
INFO - https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex2e/contrib/abntex2/tex/abntex2.cls
INFO - https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex2e/contrib/abntexto/abntexto.cls
INFO - match count: 8
INFO - directories searched count: 300
INFO - directories ignored count: 20102
INFO - output written to myfile1.txt
INFO - time: 59.2872476309999
```

and the output is written to `myfile.txt`

I don't know if this script is useful; if it looks helpful/promising, contributions welcome!

Comment: Thanks for sharing, even if I prefer to use `click`.