# New to LaTex. Where to start with side columns?

Tags: two-column

Im quite new to LaTex and would like to directly start with using it for my next thesis.

I would like to do a design like that one: 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13507

With side-columns at the pages. I found several templates where the column is always at the right or the left side. I would like to have it alternating. so that the side column will be always at the outer side of the page.

Could someone give me a hint where to start or where to find informations about how to implement this?

Thanks

Comment: the links you show have examples if what you ask for, basically you can use a standard `article` class document (single column , twoside) then `\marginpar` will by default be on the outer edge as you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add fancier packages and classes if you need them but it is best to start with a really basic structure and just add packages if you need the functionality rather than start with a complicated structure that may be poorly documented.  Marginal notes automatically appear on the outer edge, so your basic requirement is already met by the standard `article` class with no additional packages.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{article}

\extrafloats{100}

\def\zz{One two three four five six seven eight nine ten \stepcounter{enumi}\roman{enumi}. }
\def\zzz{\zz Red blue yellow green
\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\marginpar{%
\setlength\unitlength{.5pt}
\begin{picture}(200,100)
\put(30,40){\line(1,0){150}}
\put(30,40){\line(0,1){60}}
\put(30,100){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(50,100){\line(1,-4){10}}
\put(60,60){\line(1,0){100}}
\put(160,60){\line(1,-1){20}}
\put(100,50){\line(0,-1){80}}
\put(130,50){\line(0,-1){80}}
\put(100,-30){\line(1,0){30}}
\put(100,61){\line(0,1){49}}
\put(130,61){\line(0,1){49}}
\put(100,110){\line(1,0){30}}
\end{picture}}. \zz\zz Apple orange \Roman{enumi}.
\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz
\zz\zz\zz\marginpar{
\begin{picture}(100,100)
\put(50,50){\oval(50,20){}}
\put(70,65){\circle{20}}
\put(35,50){\line(1,0){30}}
\put(70,65){\circle*{2}}
\put(75,67){\line(6,-1){10}}
\put(75,63){\line(6,1){10}}
\end{picture}}\zz}

\begin{document}

\zzz\zzz\zzz
\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz
\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz

\zzz\zz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz
\zzz\zzz\zz\zzz\zzz\zz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your poroposal. Will play around a bit with your code.

Comment: Ok i have tried it and i just love it :) thanks. Is there any disadvantage if i am using the "article" class for a thesis? Or is this not important? thanks @david carlisle

Comment: @C.Hediger almost all thesis classes either load one of the standard classes and then add more customisation or start from a copy of one of the standard classes. so basically no you can always switch later if you need to, usually a university-specific thesis class is more or less normal latex for the body of the document but provides specific commands to help structure the frontmatter and title pages which often have local and strange requirements specific to each institution.

Comment: @C.Hediger if you do start from this you might want to add the `geometry` package which offers a nice interface to changing the page layout, eg if you want to make the text narrower and the sidebar wider or whatever.

Comment: +1 for the gorgeous side images :)

Answer (score 1):

`classicthesis` might be a good starting point:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326/latex-templates-for-writing-a-thesis.  Actually, one should avoid classicthesis.

Comment: Thank you very much for your proposal. Looks really good. @JohnKormylo why should i dont use classicthesis? And what do you think about memoir?

Comment: @C.Hediger I think that `memoir` is a wonderful class, adjustable to many needs. I wouldn't use anything else. (Caveat: I am the original developer of `memoir`).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are searching the `tufte-book` class. Run `texdoc tufte`for more information.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{My wonderful tesis}
\author{Someone Likeyou}
\date{\today}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{Introduction}

\begin{marginfigure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A marginfnal figure} 
\end{marginfigure}

\lipsum[1][1-5]


\lipsum[2]

\begin{marginfigure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{A marginfnal figure} 
\end{marginfigure}

\lipsum[4-6]

\begin{marginfigure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{A marginfnal figure} 
\end{marginfigure}


\end{document}
```

You can also consider the [caesar_book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134389/11604) class, included in the [sidenotes](https://ctan.org/pkg/sidenotes) package.

Comment: I too suggest "tufte-book", this is one of a fine one to proceed...