# Empty Margin inside of text body

Tags: header-footer, margins, geometry

I am trying to mimic a common textbook/study guide typesetting where every page's body (not header nor footer) have a "Notes" area on the outside margin. I have been looking at geometry, but it is non-native to have the header be text + margin. I copied the "includeall" layout in the geometry package documentation in the section "Body Size", and then a modification of that showing what I am looking for. The red text "Notes" would be great to include at the top of every page, but I can probably do that as part of the header as a floating text box, if necessary.

[image: Original Page Layout from package Geometry with header and footer set to textwidth]

[image: desired page layout modified from other image with header and footer spanning entire non printing margin width]

Comment: Note: I did manage to find "tufte-book" layout that does do a wonderful job of doing this. Although it does a lot more than just reset the body text (moving table captions, for instance). Hard to find documentation for that package, as well.

Comment: Do you know the `texdoc` program?  Just try from the OS prompt to run `texdoc tufte` or go to https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex

Comment: Try also `texdoc caesar` or search about `caesar_book`. Example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134389/11604).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use package `fancyhdr`:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[includemp]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}}
\fancyheadoffset[LE,RO]{\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}
\fancyfootoffset[LE,RO]{\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{\headrulewidth}% to show the width of footer

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum
\lipsum[1]\marginpar{\raggedright\lipsum[2]}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you could use package `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[includemp]{geometry}

\usepackage[
  headwidth=textwithmarginpar,
  headsepline,plainheadsepline,% to show the width of header
  footwidth=textwithmarginpar,
  footsepline,plainfootsepline% to show the width of footer
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum
\lipsum[1]\marginpar{\raggedright\lipsum[2]}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Then you could add layers for the margin pars:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[includemp]{geometry}

\usepackage[
  headwidth=textwithmarginpar,
  headsepline,plainheadsepline,% to show the width of header
  footwidth=textwithmarginpar,
  footsepline,plainfootsepline% to show the width of footer
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  oddpage,
  background,
  textarea,
  addhoffset=\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep,
  width=\marginparwidth,
  mode=picture,
  contents=\putUL{\raisebox{\dp\strutbox}{Notes:}}%
    % draw marginpar border:
    \putLL{\line(1,0){\LenToUnit{\layerwidth}}}%
    \putLR{\line(0,1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
    \putUR{\line(-1,0){\LenToUnit{\layerwidth}}}%
    \putUL{\line(0,-1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
]{odd.marginpar}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  evenpage,
  background,
  textarea,
  addhoffset=\dimexpr-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth,
  width=\marginparwidth,
  mode=picture,
  contents=\putUL{\raisebox{\dp\strutbox}{Notes:}}%
    % draw margin par border:
    \putLL{\line(1,0){\LenToUnit{\layerwidth}}}%
    \putLR{\line(0,1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
    \putUR{\line(-1,0){\LenToUnit{\layerwidth}}}%
    \putUL{\line(0,-1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
]{even.marginpar}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{odd.marginpar,even.marginpar}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{odd.marginpar,even.marginpar}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum
\lipsum[1]\marginpar{\raggedright\lipsum[2]}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! I had been trying to play with fancyhdr and it always put the header inside the textwidth. I will try this out with my more complicated document.