# Problem with side images

Tags: wrapfigure

I have a problem with the environment wrapfigure because it makes a lot more space even after there is no image.

Here is an image of the problem:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\vspace{-0.15cm}
\includegraphics[width=0.35 \textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A mayor temperatura la emisión de radiación del cuerpo negro se dispara hacia longitudes menores acercándose al visible}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

If someone could help that would be incredible thank you.

Comment: From my experience, `wrapfigure` requires manual adjustments after the text contents are fixed. It is somehow inevitable.

Comment: How I do that? Because I have no idea

Comment: You could try replacing `wrapfigure` with the plain TeX macro `\InsertBoxL` (or `InsertBoxR` if you prefer), from `insbox` .

Comment: @alvaritomendez Maybe move the wrapfigure up a little or set the image smaller. But all these are considered only after the text contents are finished so that the position will no longer change.

Comment: @teddyvanJerry The problem it isn't withe size of the image the space it's maybe a little bit less but still a lot

Comment: @alvaritomendez Yes, I know that quite well. It is annoying to use `wrapfigure` when the contents overflow the frame and the whole page arrangement got messed up. I reckon it is because the inner calculation mechanism of `wrapfigure`. Therefore, you need to void this kink of overflow and keep the figure strictly within the page frame. They are the adjustments you need after fixing the text contents.

Comment: please don't show code as an image.  The wrapfig documentation is explicit that it is not supported to wrap in lists and from your output it looks like you have it in a list.

Comment: Run `texdoc wrapfig`, the manual is short but clear about the  idiosyncrasies of this environment. Pay attention specially to the "Placement and Floating" in page 2. BTW, depending on your contents and taste, if you planned use several wrapped figures,  consider avoid that and  use  a two column layout (or the tufte-book class, if you need a wider main text for equations or whatever).

Comment: @Fran Could you explain more of the second option because my project is like a math book and I'm tired of the text-image-text structure and I wanted to change it to make it less boring

Comment: @alvaritomendez  The layout of tufte-book  or caesar_book classes  is one column of text bit with a wide margin to place images and tables, tthat also can be placed in the text column or takin the fill with, as well as the images. See an example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134389/11604) or just run `texdoc tufte`.